# To send more than 65535 byte by dataoutputstream.writeUTF(string)

Tags: android, sockets

When I try to write down more than 65535 byte at method call DataOutput.writeUTF (String),
I receive UTFDataFormatException.How can I avoid that

Comment: how about spliting your string in multiple strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You will have to use `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()`, and `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` to read it.